# is it possible to read xdata from DWG in Navisworks using COM interface?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

I"m trying to get xdata from selected entity inside Navisworks window.
Navisworks Manage 2023 can read DWG files. Model entity can get xdata (linked list) attached using AcDbEntity->xdata(..) method.
Is any interface in COM environment available to read xdata?

One discussion on Navisworks forum mentioned a way to link Category Tab to outside SQL DB. But this approach is not dynamic so i'm looking for another way to create props in custom Category Tab.
Thank you,
Gennady

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: following request to add details. AcDbObject in ObjectARX has methods to communicate with output environment dwgIn/dwgOut, xData/setXdata. Should be similar methods to post Category (OE reader) properties from dwg to Navisworks Manager (LcOpDwgEntityAttrib?)

Comment: it is a known limitation. Navisworks cannot read out Xdata from DWG. The customer has to wrap the information in an Object Enabler (Custom Object) and install the Object Enabler on the target machine.. This means you have to be able to program on AutoCAD API.

Comment: Thank you, Xianodong Liang, for the update. Source code for OE is actulally in my hands but there is no any sample doc on how to post properties from OE (dbx) to Navisworks Manager. It should be some interface to post props from OE in form of LcOpDwgEntityAttib. Any idea where to find such desctiption?